# Keep alive streaming ffmpeg rtmp

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

How can I keep a streaming connection alive when the file is over?
I am using ffmpeg 4
I tried the timeout option but it doesn't work, so my example would be:

ffmpeg -i input.webm -timeout -f flv rtmp://streaming

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you don't. Once rtmp is unpublished, there is no point in keeping the TCP session active.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -y -re -i "input.webm" -acodec copy -vcodec copy -strict unofficial -f flv "rtmp://streaming"

Comment: While this might answer the question, a bit of explanation would be extremely helpful, click edit and please type in some explanation.